# IP address exclusion algorithm

Tags: python, generator

The below algorithm is supposed to take a list of input IPs/networks and a list of IPs/networks to exclude, and return a list of networks that don't include any of the IPs/networks to exclude...

Please review it and provide me with some feedback!

```
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

def recurse_exclude(supernet_list, exclude_list):
    # For some reason, this only works if we force the generators into lists
    for supernet in list(supernet_list):
        for exclude in exclude_list:
            try:
                excluded_list = recurse_exclude(list(supernet.address_exclude(exclude)), exclude_list)
            except ValueError:
                # Ignore when the IP/net to exclude was not in the supernet
                continue
            else:
                return list(excluded_list)
    return supernet_list

supernet_list = [IPv4Network('1.1.0.0/24')]
output = recurse_exclude(supernet_list, exclude_list=[IPv4Network('1.1.0.0/25'),IPv4Network('1.1.0.128/26')])
```

Comment: Please clarify your intentions. If you're looking for an explanation of the code provided, we don't do that. Does the code work to your satisfaction?

Comment: I wrote this code, I was hoping for some feedback on my logic. I shall change the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Review

1. Python and recursion are not the best match, instead use loops

   It could even be done with list comprehension

   `return [ip if ip not in exclude for ip in subnet]`
2. Alter your imports to use one of the two not both

   I suggest to use `from ipaddress import IPv4Network` because that seems to be only thing imported from the library.
3. Use sets!

   Lists are O(N), while sets are O(1)!

   Secondly it's quite easy to subtract sets simply use `set(c) = set(a) - set(b)`

## Example

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

exclude = set(IPv4Network('1.1.0.0/25')) | set(IPv4Network('1.1.0.128/26'))
net = set(IPv4Network('1.1.0.0/24'))

print(net - exclude)
```

Comment: Lists can be O(1) per element as well, if you know they are sorted (which `list(IPv4Network(...))` is), and use that fact to only do a single pass over each list.